# JavaScript - Performance issues with preloading images using Image constructor

Tags: javascript, image, performance, preloading

I'm preloading some images in my web application (which is built with React) as below:

```js
preloadImages = (imageUrls) => {
  imagesUri.forEach(imageUrl => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = imageUrl;
  })
}
```

**My question is:** since I'm creating new `Image` objects from an array of image URLs, say 10 images, does this have any impact on performance? I'm not sure whether I need to remove the created element since the variable `img` is scoped inside `forEach`.

Comment: Are you encountering a real world problem? Paranoia questions aren't the best fit for SO

Comment: @JuanMendes yes, I'm receiving 4 image URLs from an API, and these images should be loaded into a menu. The menu would be opened when a user clicks on it, so as soon as my app receives these images, I want to do a preloading, thus the user experience, in my opinion, would be much better.

Comment: What I am asking is: is doing this preloading causing any problems, is it not working? Open ended questions about whether you should do something are not a good fit for SO. SO is for problems you actually encountered but you already have a solution here. Your question implies you have a performance issue but I don't think you do

Answer (score 0):

The img variable is not a problem here.

But performance will decrease because you probably preload images you do not need immediately.

Check your browser debugger -> network tab.

You'll see the threads and performance impact.

And if you are talking about the HEAP, it will detect if your new Object is used or not. And it remove the object automatically if is not used.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not preloading every single image that's being used in the app. There are only 4 images that must be preloaded in a specific condition, so I'm only worrying about the JS performance here.

Comment: I edited the post in that way. Performance will not be impacted, and the memory manager will removed them after using them.